# How does the WSCF.Blue DataContract generation feature work?

Tags: c#, wcf, datacontractserializer, xmlserializer, wscf.blue

I'm trying to figure out how the WSCF Blue DataContract generation feature works.

It's documented here: http://alexmg.com/post/2009/09/01/Data-contract-generation-is-now-available-in-WSCFblue.aspx

I have a set of WSDL and XSD files from which we can use the "regular" method to create web service code.

The service generated does not allow you to use data contracts at the client end, meaning we get lots of Array types instead of List types.

Or more accurately, we can't get Lists, only Arrays so this means it's not using DataContracts.

So, when generating service code on the server side I get two options.

1. Use the regular option, generates an abstract class from which we create a concrete Service class
2. Use the "Generate Data Contract" option. This creates a .cs file containing just classes representing the the Xsd types, no abstract classes for the service.

So if I then try to generate the service classes with the regular options, I now have lots of duplicate classes representing the Xsd types.

I clearly have the wrong end of the stick.

Has anybody managed to make WSCF.blue work with DataContracts instead of the XmlSerializer?

Comment: Taking a closer look at the code, it appears that there is no significant difference between the generated code files. Maybe this is just an unfinished feature in wscf.blue?